# Identify if a Library item is a folder or not in CSOM

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, library

I have Library on which I have created a ribbon button. On click of the button I am trying to identify if the selected item is a folder or a file. below if the code snippet that I am using:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web(); 
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context); 
var currentLibrary = web.get_lists().getById(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(context)); 
var index;
for (index in items) {
    var selectedItem = currentLibrary.getItemById(items[index].id);
    // Need to identify if 'selectedItem' is folder or not
    console.log("FileSystemObjectType = " + selectedItem.FileSystemObjectType); // Returns 'undefined'
    console.log("get_file = " + selectedItem.get_file()); // Returns 'SP.ListItem' object
    console.log("get_folder = " + selectedItem.get_folder()); // Returns 'SP.ListItem' object
}
```

Taking reference from [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/ac136a64-ebc4-4561-aad4-8baffc6908c3/check-if-listitem-is-folder-or-item-using-client-object-mode) I tried to use `FileSystemObjectType` but in my case it ends up showing `undefined` for both file and folder. Also if I try to check if the selected item is a file or folder using below code it always return true.

```
if(item.FileSystemObjectType == SP.FileSystemObjectType.Folder) {
    // Always returns true
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I identify if the selected item in Library is a file or a folder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example contains the following errors/typos:

To get fs object type use the following syntax:

```
var fsObjType = selectedItem.get_fileSystemObjectType();
```

Another point is, `ListItem` object have to be requested first before getting it's value, this is why in your example it will not work.

---

In fact, you don't have to request `ListItem` object in order to determine its type using [SP.ListItem.fileSystemObjectType Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee548025(v=office.14).aspx).

[SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409526(v=office.14).aspx) returns an array of objects, for example: `[{"id" 1: ,"fsObjType": "0"}]` , where `fsObjType` specifies file system object type, the following example demonstrates how to determine the type of selected object.

Example

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web(); 
var selItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context); //not SP.ListItem collection!
for (var index in selItems) {
    var selItem = selItems[index];
    switch(selItem.fsObjType){
        case "0":
          console.log('File has been selected');
        break;
        case "1":
          console.log('Folder has been selected');
        break;
    }
}
```